# How can I store the text entered into a html textarea into a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I want to store the text users enter into a textarea in a website into a javascript variable in order to compare it to another variable already defined.

How would you do it? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: by grabbing the `value` of the text area

Comment: `$('#textarea id').val();`

Comment: var n=$('txtarea').val();

Comment: The same way you get the value a user enters into any other input.

Comment: It's a duplicate question - stop abusing the 'Unclear what you are asking' close reason. If you can't tell what the OP is asking you need glasses instead of voting priviledges

Comment: funny, all those downvotes.. still gets answer more quickly as average questions..

Answer (score 1):

**using jquery**

```
var n=$('#textarea_id').val();
```

**using javascript**

```
var n=document.getElementById('textAreaID').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
var textareaValue = document.getElementById('textAreadID').value
```

Replace `textAreadID` with your `textarea` `id`.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
var str = "compare with me",
value = $('textarea[name="yourareaname"]').val();

if(str == value) {
    alert('hell yeah');
}
```